# How to calculate GPA by automatically detect credit hour from subject code and grade point from marks

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create only 2 textboxes for subject code and marks.

For subject code eg: AAAA3143 and marks eg:100

For credit hour, it will automatically detect by last number of subject code eg: 3

Here is the marks, grade and point:

```
80-100 (A=4),
65-79 (B=3),
50-64 (C=2),
35-49 (D=1),
0-34 (F=0)
```

For grade point will be credit hour times point eg: 3*4 = 12

To calculate GPA total grade point divide by total credit hours eg: 12/3 = 4

And here is the code for subject code & marks to detect automatically but I didn't know how to calculate the GPA from this code

```
      if ($mark <= 100 && $mark >=80){
          $code = substr($code,8);
          $point = $code * 4;
      }
      else if ($mark <= 79 && $mark >=65){
          $code = substr($code,8);
          $point = $code * 3;
      }
      else if ($mark <= 64 && $mark >=50){
          $code = substr($code,8);
          $point = $code * 2;
      }
      else if ($mark <= 49 && $mark >=35){
          $code = substr($code,8);
          $point = $code * 1;
      }
      else{
          $code = substr($code,8);
          $point = $code * 0;
      }
```

Here is the code that I already made:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GPA CALCULATOR</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="banner">
    <h1>GPA CALCULATOR</h1>
  </div>

  <form action="" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="code1" id="code1" placeholder="eg: AAAA3113" /></td>
        <td><input type="mark" name="mark" placeholder="eg: 100" id="mark1" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="code2" id="code2" /></td>
        <td><input type="mark" name="mark" placeholder="" id="mark2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="code3" id="code3" /></td>
        <td><input type="mark" name="mark" placeholder="" id="mark3" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="code4" id="code4" /></td>
        <td><input type="mark" name="mark" placeholder="" id="mark4" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="code5" id="code5" /></td>
        <td><input type="mark" name="mark" placeholder="" id="mark5" /></td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calcy()" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

  <div class="showdata">
    <p id="showData"></p>
  </div>

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```